# How to reuse defined style in control template resources

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplates

I am new to WPF. I dont know how to do this.

I have this style defined -

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="StandardButton">

<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBackground}"/>

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>

</Style>
```

I have a control template -

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">

<ControlTemplate.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" /* Here I need to put above defined style */></Style> 

    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all `Buttons` in your `ControlTemplate` to use the `Style` just remove the `x:Key` from the style and add to the `ControlTemplate.Resources`

```
<ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
    </Style>
</ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

`Styles` with an `x:Key` will have to be declared on the control like `Style="{StaticResource StandardButton}"`, to apply to all controls in the scope of the `Resources` you only have to declare the `TargetType`

If you already have a `Style` defined in your higher level `Resources` and you want to apply to all the `Buttons` in your `ControlTemplate` you can use the `BasedOn` property.

Example:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
   <ControlTemplate.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardButton}" />
   </ControlTemplate.Resources>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This will apply `StandardButton` `Style` to all Buttons in the scope of the `Resources` it was defined, in this case all the `Buttons` in the `ExpanderTemplate`

Comment: I can do this, but I have a lot of other controls to refer this button style. Also I have given just an example. The style has a lot of code and I can't put it as a resource in each control. I want to refer it everywhere in resourceDirectory

Comment: so you want ALL buttons to have this style?

Comment: Updated answer with what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your style using StaticResource and the key name of the Resource you defined

```
Style="{StaticResource StandardButton}"
```

Comment: I need all the buttons in Expander must be of this style. Style is not having property called Style FYI.